# Getting attributes values from a node in XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML file and i want to get values of the nodes attributes in it, it works efficiently when the node is usual but is the case of nodes named like something:something it didn't give me back any result, just null.
The XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
<channel>
  <title>Yahoo! Weather - Sunnyvale, CA</title>
  <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Sunnyvale__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA1116_f.html</link>
  <description>Yahoo! Weather for Sunnyvale, CA</description>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <lastBuildDate>Fri, 18 Dec 2009 9:38 am PST</lastBuildDate>
  <ttl>60</ttl>
  <yweather:location city="Sunnyvale" region="CA"   country="United States"/>
  <yweather:units temperature="F" distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph"/>
</channel>
</rss>
```

The Java Code :

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//rss/@version");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
System.out.println(result);
```

the previous java code works efficiently but when replacing  `//rss/@version` with 
`//rss/channel/yweather:location/@city` it returns me null.

Comment: You're not registering that namespace anywhere. Read the comments in your last question again, exactly the same problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So did I, nothing to complain about anymore :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the part before the : is called a *namespace*. It is quite an important concept in XML.
To retrieve a value with a namespace you have to make the context aware of the namespace. You can do this using

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(context);
```

`context` must be an implementation of NamespaceContext. In this case, the namspaces are defined within the XML so it might be good to have a namespace resolver which can get the namespaces from the document directly. This class is exactly doing this:

```
public class UniversalNamespaceResolver implements NamespaceContext {
    private Document sourceDocument;

    public UniversalNamespaceResolver(Document document) {
        sourceDocument = document;
    }

    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
            return sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
        } else {
            return sourceDocument.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
        }
    }

    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        return sourceDocument.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
    }

    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Read more about it at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-nmspccontext/